# Is there a closed form for $ \int_0^1 {x^a \over {(1+x)^2}} dx $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I know that if a is an integer I could substitute $ t = x+1 $ and get a closed-ish form (a finite series) using the binomial theorem. I tried using the binomial series but the series I get is very messy. I also tried expanding the denominator, using the fact that $ {1 \over {(1+u)^2}} = \sum_0^\infty (-1)^n(n+1)u^n $ if $u<1$, but after swapping the integral and the series and integrating I end up with a divergent series.
I really feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't quite figure out what.

Comment: Lookup Beta integral.

Comment: You can. Polynomial of rational coefficient, (if integrable) can always be represented by elementary functions

Comment: @YvesDaoust The beta function would work if the upper bound was $ \infty $ or if I had a $-$ instead of a $+$ and a power greater than -1.

Comment: @user12986714 if a isn't an integer that function isn't a ratio of polynomials.

Comment: Chances are that its Taylor series are going to converge. Maybe try to expand it and integrate term by term?

Comment: @bringradical: if a change of variable doesn't work, then you have an incomplete Beta.

Comment: By the way, "serie" is not a word. The singular is "series" and the plural is also "series," it's just one of those words. I edited the post.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes, but one day it may go the way of "pease" and "cherries."  "Biceps" is already on the slippery slope.

Comment: @user12986714 That's what the OP tried, and it didn't work.  You get $\sum(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{n+a+1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $a\ge1$. By integration by parts and $x\to \sqrt x$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^1\frac{x^a}{(1+x)^2}dx\\
&=&-\int_0^1x^ad\bigg(\frac{1}{1+x}\bigg)=-\frac{x^a}{1+x}\bigg|_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{ax^{a-1}}{1+x}dx\\
&=&-\frac12+a\int_0^1\frac{x^{a-1}-x^a}{1-x^2}dx\\
&=&-\frac12+\frac12a\int_0^1\frac{x^{\frac12a-1}-x^{\frac{a-1}{2}}}{1-x}dx\\
&=&-\frac12+\frac12a\bigg(\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{\frac{a-1}{2}}}{1-x}dx-\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{\frac12a-1}}{1-x}dx\bigg)\\
&=&-\frac12+\frac a2(H_{\frac{a-1}{2}}-H_{\frac12a-1}).
\end{eqnarray}
Use the same way for $|a|<1$.

Comment: What's the meaning of $H$ here?

Comment: @S.H.W Harmonic numbers, for non-integers they're defined as $\psi(n+1)+\gamma$ where $\psi$ is the digamma function and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: @S.H.W, the harmonic number $H(a)$ is defined by $$ H(a)=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{a}}{1-x}dx. $$

Comment: @bringradical Okay, thanks.

Comment: @xpaul Very nice answer. Is there a closed formula for $H(a)$?

Comment: @S.H.W, the harmonic number is the harmonic number and there is no closed form.

Comment: @xpaul Thank you for your replies.