# Area of region enclosed by $y=0$, $x=1$ and $y=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}k(-x)^k$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, polynomials, area

Let $A_n$ be the area of the region enclosed by $y=0$, $x=1$ and $y=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}k(-x)^k$.

[image]

> Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$.

Numerical investigation suggests that the answer is $\frac12$.

**Context**

I just made up the polynomial $y=-x+2x^2-3x^3+4x^4- \dots+2nx^{2n}$, and discovered that there is a thin region bounded by this curve, the $x$-axis and $x=1$, whose area doesn't seem to vanish as $n\to\infty$.

**My attempt**

To find a closed form of the polynomial, let $S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}k(-x)^k$.

$S+Sx$ is mostly a geometric series, and we get $S=\dfrac{2nx^{2n+2}+(2n+1)x^{2n+1}-x}{(1+x)^2}$.

Then we can try to evaluate $\int_{\alpha}^1 S dx$, where $\alpha$ is the positive root of $S$.

[There is a way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3656783/398708) to evaluate $\int_0^1 S dx$, which might be adapted to $\int_\alpha^1 S dx$, but since I don't know how to  find $\alpha$, this approach doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nice question ............ +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can prove your observation using a few inequalities.
First, from
$$2n\alpha^{2n+2} + (2n+1)\alpha^{2n+1} - \alpha = 0$$
we get
$$\alpha^{2n} = \frac{1}{2n\alpha + 2n+1};$$
then using $0 < \alpha < 1$ on the right-hand side gives us
$$\sqrt[2n]\frac{1}{4n+1} < \alpha < \sqrt[2n]\frac{1}{2n+1}. \tag{1}$$

Next, in the interval $\alpha \le x \le 1$ we have
$$\frac{1}{4} \le \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} \le \frac{1}{(\alpha+1)^2}$$
so we can bound the integral of $S$ in terms of a simpler integral $I$:
$$\frac{1}{4}\cdot I \le \int_\alpha^1 S \,dx \le \frac{1}{(\alpha+1)^2}\cdot I$$

where
$$\begin{align*}I &= \int_\alpha^1 (2nx^{2n+2} + (2n+1)x^{2n+1} - x) \, dx \\
&= \left(\frac{2n}{2n+3} + \frac{2n+1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{2n}{2n+3}\alpha^{2n+3} + \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\alpha^{2n+2} - \frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\right).
\end{align*}$$

Now, from equation $(1)$ we see that $\alpha \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$, while $\alpha^{2n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
Hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n}{2n+3}\alpha^{2n+3} + \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\alpha^{2n+2} - \frac{1}{2}\alpha^2
= 0 + 0 - \frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}.$$

So $\lim_{n\to\infty}I = 2$, and thus

$$\frac{1}{2} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{4}I \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\alpha^1 S\,dx \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(\alpha+1)^2} I = \frac{1}{2}.$$

So $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\alpha^1 S\,dx = \frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Nice answer ...............   +1

Answer (score 5):

Let $\alpha$ be the solution to $$\alpha^{2n}=\frac{1}{2n\alpha+2n+1} \,. \tag{1}$$
Integrating yields $$S=\int_\alpha^1 {\rm d}x \sum_{k=1}^{2n}k (-x)^k =\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \left(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\right) (-1)^k \left(1-\alpha^{k+1}\right) \\
=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \left( 1 - \alpha^{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{\alpha^{k+1}}{k+1} \right) = S_1+S_2+S_3+S_4 \, .$$
Making use of the geometric series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x^k = \frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}$ and the logarithmic series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \, x^k=\log(1+x)$, we now have $$S_1=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k = 0 \\
S_2=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-\alpha)^{k+1} = \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha+1}\left(1-\alpha^{2n}\right)=\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n\alpha+2n+1}\right) \\
S_3=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1} - \sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1} = 1-\log(2) - \color{red}{\frac{1}{4n} + O(1/n^2)} \\
S_4=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \frac{\alpha^{k+1}}{k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\alpha^{k+1}}{k+1} - \sum_{k=2n+1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\alpha^{k+1}}{k+1} = \log(1+\alpha)-\alpha + \color{blue}{O(1/n^2)} \, .$$
The latter $O$ follows from $$\left|\sum_{k=2n+1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\alpha^{k+1}}{k+1}\right| \stackrel{{\rm s.b.p.}}{=} \left|\sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2}\right) \sum_{l=2n+1}^k (-1)^l \alpha^{l+1} \right| \\
=\left|\sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2}\right) \frac{\alpha^{2+2n}}{\alpha+1} \left((-\alpha)^{k-2n} - 1\right) \right| \\
\leq \frac{2\alpha^2}{\alpha+1} \frac{1}{2n\alpha+2n+1} \sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2}\right) = \color{blue}{O(1/n^2)} \, .$$

The former $\frac{1}{4n} + O(1/n^2)$ can be derived as follows (using the telescoping series and summation by parts again)
$$\sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1} \stackrel{{\rm s.b.p.}}{=} \sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty \frac{1+(-1)^{k+1}}{2} \left( \frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right) \\
= \frac12 \sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2} \right) + \frac12 \sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)(k+2)} \\ \stackrel{{\rm s.b.p.}}{=} \frac{1}{4(n+1)} + \underbrace{\frac12 \sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty \frac{1+(-1)^{k+1}}{2\,(k+2)} \left( \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+3} \right)}_{\leq \, \sum\limits_{k=2n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)} \, = \, O(1/n^2)} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{4n} + O(1/n^2)} \, .$$

Putting everything together gives
$$S=\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n\alpha+2n+1}\right) + 1 - \alpha + \log\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{4n} + O(1/n^2) \, . \tag{2}$$

Now from (1) we have
$$\alpha=\left(\frac{1}{2n\alpha+2n+1}\right)^{1/2n}$$
and making the ansatz $\alpha=1+\frac{c_1\log(n)+c_2}{n}$ and expanding the root up to first order, we find consistency if $$\alpha=1-\frac{\log(4n)}{2n} + o(1/n)$$ with small $o$-notation.
Inserting this result into (2) and expanding for large $n$ finally gives $$S=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3+\log(4n)}{8n} + o(1/n) \, .$$

Comment: In my second answer, I recovered the logarithmic contribution. Thanks for pointing my error. Cheers

Comment: Working crazy to inverse Lambert function, I obtained $$\alpha=\left(\frac{8 x+5}{2}\right)^{-\frac{2}{4 x+\sqrt{2}}}$$ Fot he values given in my first answer, it gives $$\{0.948632,0.955529,0.960684,0.964696,0.967915,0.970559\}$$

Answer (score 3):

If $y= -x + 2x^2 - 3x^3 ...$

Then $y$ can also be written as $$x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^kx^k=x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{-x}{1+x}=-\frac{x}{(1+x)^2} $$

This is valid for $-1<x<1$ .
This does not seem to have the area you are trying to measure as the sole root of this function is at $x=0$, but the area bounded between the lines stated is:

$$ \int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}dx = \ln(\lvert x+1\rvert)+\frac{1}{1+x}=\ln2-\frac{1}{2} $$

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: How is that formula valid when $x=-1$?

Comment: @Gary Okay, lets delete our comments now!

Comment: Btw, this does not answer the question at all. Why so many upvotes?

Answer (score 3):

The key equation being
$$2n\alpha^{2n+1}+(2n+1)\alpha^{2n}-1=0\quad \text{with} \quad \frac 12 \leq\alpha <1$$
playing with inequalities, it is simple to show that we have
$$\alpha_{\text{min}} =(4 n+1)^{-\frac{1}{2 n}}<\alpha <(4 n+1)^{-\frac{1}{2 n+1}}=\alpha_{\text{max}}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & \alpha_{\text{min}} & \alpha & \alpha_{\text{max}}\\
 10 & 0.830540 &  0.834053 & 0.837917 \\
 20 & 0.895958 &  0.897127 & 0.898362 \\
 30 & 0.923181 &  0.923774 & 0.924392 \\
 40 & 0.938458 &  0.938820 & 0.939194 \\
 50 & 0.948349 &  0.948594 & 0.948847 \\
 60 & 0.955322 &  0.955501 & 0.955683 \\
 70 & 0.960526 &  0.960662 & 0.960801 \\
 80 & 0.964571 &  0.964678 & 0.964787 \\
  90 & 0.967813 &  0.967900 & 0.967988 \\
 100 & 0.970475 &  0.970547 & 0.970620 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Since
$$f_n(\alpha_{\text{max}})>0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f_n(\alpha_{\text{max}})\times f''_n(\alpha_{\text{max}}) >0 \quad \forall n$$ by Darbous theorem, the first iterate of Newton method will provide a better upper bound much closer to the solution. It is given by
$$\alpha_1=\alpha_{\text{max}}\left(1-\frac 1{2n}\frac{1-\alpha_{\text{max}}} {1+\alpha_{\text{max}}} \right)$$
which is a significant improvement.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \alpha_1 & \alpha \\
 10 & 0.834222 &  0.834053 \\
 20 & 0.897160 &  0.897127 \\
 30 & 0.923786 &  0.923774 \\
 40 & 0.938826 &  0.938820 \\
 50 & 0.948598 &  0.948594 \\
 60 & 0.955503 &  0.955501 \\
 70 & 0.960663 &  0.960662 \\
 80 & 0.964679 &  0.964678 \\
 90 & 0.967901 &  0.967900 \\
 100 & 0.970547 &  0.970547 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I must mention here that, expanded for large $n$
$$\alpha_1=1-\frac{\log(4n)}{2n}+\frac{\log (n) \log (16 e n)+\left(4 \log ^2(2)+2 \log (2)-1\right) } {8 n^2 }+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ the first term being already given by @Diger.

Since we have the analytical expression of the integral (given in my second answer), computing
$$S=\int_{\alpha}^1 \dfrac{2nx^{2n+2}+(2n+1)x^{2n+1}-x}{(1+x)^2} \,dx$$
$$S=\int_{\alpha}^1  \frac{x^{2 n+1}}{(x+1)^2}\,dx+\int_{\alpha}^1 \frac{2 n x^{2 n+1}}{x+1}\,dx-\int_{\alpha}^1 \frac{x}{(x+1)^2}\,dx$$
$$S=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-\alpha }{2 (1+\alpha)}+\log \left(\frac{1+\alpha}{2}\right)+\frac{\alpha ^{2 n+1}}{1+\alpha }+B_{-\frac{1}{\alpha }}(-2 n,0)+$$
$$2 n \left(B_{-\frac{1}{\alpha }}(-2 n,0)-B_{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}(-2 n-1,0)\right)+$$ $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi ^{(0)}(-n)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Using $\alpha=\alpha_1$ and expanding the results
$$S=\frac 12-\frac{3+\log (4 n)}{8 n}+\frac{\log (n) \log \left(16 e^3 n\right)+2 \left(3 \log (2 e)+2 \log ^2(2)\right) }{32\,n^2 }+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
the first term being already given by @Diger.

Comment: Right when I saw the tables I new it was you :) $+1$

Comment: The $1/n$ term is not correct, I think.

Comment: Your left bound fails at $n=288$, where the root is $0.987845...$ while your lower bound is $1-\frac{7}{2n} = 0.987847...$. I agree with Diger; the asymptotic should be $1 - \frac{\log(4n)}{2n}$.

Comment: @Diger. I agree with you. I suspect that it is because the logarithmic term is not in the approximation of $\alpha$.

Comment: @BenjaminWright.   I agree with you. I suspect that it is because the logarithmic term is not in the approximation of α.

Answer (score 2):

*I prefer to add a separate answer.*

Even if not the simplest, we know exactly the vanue of the integral as a function of $\alpha$ since if

$$S=\int_{\alpha}^1 \dfrac{2nx^{2n+2}+(2n+1)x^{2n+1}-x}{(1+x)^2} \,dx$$ then
$$2 (\alpha +1) (-1)^{2 n} S=$$
$$-(-1)^{2 n} \left(-2 (\alpha +1) \log \left(\frac{\alpha
   +1}{2}\right)-\left((\alpha +1) H_n\right)+(\alpha +1)
   H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}-2\right)-2 (2 (\alpha +1) n+1) (-\alpha )^{2
   n+2}+2 (\alpha +1) (2 n+1)^2 B_{-\alpha }(2 n+2,0)-8 (\alpha
   +1) n (n+1) B_{-\alpha }(2 n+3,0) $$ is valid even for non integer values of $n$.

On the other side
$$n=\frac 12\left(\frac{W_{-1}(t)}{\log (\alpha)}-\frac{1}{\alpha+1}\right) \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\alpha ^{\frac{1}{\alpha +1}}\,\frac{\log (\alpha )}{\alpha +1}$$

Then, what remains is to perform an asymptotic analysis of $S$ when $\alpha \to 1^-$ and then back to $n$.

Converting some nasty constants to decimals, this gives as  *approximations*

$$\color{blue}{\alpha \sim  1-\frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{35}{87}+\frac{261 }{472}\log (n)\right)}$$ and
$$\color{blue}{S \sim \frac 1 2 -\frac 1 n\left(\frac{11}{38}+\frac{131 }{666}\log (n)\right)}$$